# How to add values in pandas if order is changed

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataframe

```
 Subj2  Subj3   Subj4   0
    CHE MAT PHY 490
    BIO CHE PHY 471
    CRS GOV LIT 381
    LIT GOV CRS 211
    ECO GOV MAT 116
    CRS ECO GOV 108
    GOV CRS LIT 74
    GOV ECO CRS 73
    MAT PHY CHE 68
    MAT CHE PHY 57
```

Here I want to add `CHE MAT PHY, MAT PHY CHE, MAT CHE PHY` value such as `490+68+57`. Because they are same, just order is changed. And also `CRS GOV LIT, LIT GOV CRS and GOV CRS LIT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `numpy.sort`

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('Sub')] = np.sort(df.filter(like='Sub').values,1)
out = df.groupby(df.columns[:3].tolist()).sum()
Out[27]: 
                     0
Subj2 Subj3 Subj4     
BIO   CHE   PHY    471
CHE   MAT   PHY    615
CRS   ECO   GOV    181
      GOV   LIT    666
ECO   GOV   MAT    116
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
df.iloc[:,:3] = np.sort(df.iloc[:,:3])[:, ::-1]# Sort values in the subjects
df.groupby(['Subj2', 'Subj3', 'Subj4'])['0'].sum().to_frame()#aggregate



                    0
Subj2 Subj3 Subj4     
GOV   ECO   CRS    181
LIT   GOV   CRS    666
MAT   GOV   ECO    116
PHY   CHE   BIO    471
      MAT   CHE    615
```